# What is the camping tent used for?

Tags: dayz-2012

I came across a camping tent while playing, and the description says it acts as "extended safe storage" for items. After pitching the tent I noticed I was able to "save it", in addition to storing things inside of it. I assumed that saving a tent would save the tents location and contents in the games persistent server, and then the next time I loaded up the game my tent and its contents would still be there. Sadly, however, I was [killed by a bandit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65890/what-is-a-bandit) before I could test this theory.

What is the purpose of a camping tent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this unofficial DayZ Wiki](http://dayzwiki.com/):

> Tents are items that offer a source of storage players. They do not
>   save from server to server but on the originating server they were
>   deployed on. Deployed tents cannot be stolen, however the items inside
>   can be.

So, tents stay on the server they were pitched on and do not follow you to other servers.

It also says the Save command "properly saves a tent although there still is a chance that a server will eat your tent no matter what."

More info [here](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tent).

Answer (score 2):

The tents are used for storage, they save through server restarts. You use the save option to save the contents.

Comment: Will a pitched tent come with me if I switch servers, or will it only be found on the server I pitched it in?

Comment: @Wipqozn Tents only exist on the server where you pitch them.